# ¿Cómo crear un directorio que sume un numero más al anterior usando el comando md en ms-dos?

Tags: php, c#, windows

Tengo las carpetas

> 001-2018
>
> 002-2018
>
> 003-2018

Quiero que un comando de de la consola MS-DOS como `mkdir` ó `md` me cree siempre uno mas. Sin tener que escribirlo

algo así como

```
md $-2018 + 1
```

o no sé pues no sé la sintaxis.

Si alguien tiene idea. Mil Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Tu pregunta sobre que es? consola? c#? php?

Comment: Has mirado la ayuda del comando? Es muy posible que tengas que hacerte un .bat para buscar el último directorio, sumarle 1 y crearlo

Comment: Soy muy novato en esto de los bat, investigaré un poco mas, si alguien tiene una solución genial sería de gran ayuda :-)

Comment: por que las etiquetas de PHP y C#?

Answer (score 0):

Soy nueva y tube que investigar un poco pero quedaría algo asi.

```
cls
echo off
set /A counter=0
echo indique el numero incremental de nombre de la carpeta: 
set /P numvar=
echo indique el numero de carpetas que desea:
set /P carp=

:loop
if %counter% LEQ %carp% (
    md %numvar%-2018
    set /a numvar = %numvar% + 1
    set /a counter = %counter% +1
    goto :loop
    )
pause
```